# Is there a way to watch Netflix on Linux?

Tags: linux, video, silverlight, mono-framework

I'm trying to get Netflix to work on a Ubuntu box; [Moonlight](http://mono-project.com/Moonlight) looked like it could run Netflix, but the version i tried(1.0.1) didn't work.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reliable way to watch Netflix movies on Linux at the moment is to order the DVD.

Netflix requires support for Silverlight 2, however Moonlight only supports Silverlight 1 technology at the moment. The [roadmap](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap#Upcoming_Releases) says that beta support for Silverlight 2 will be debuted in September.

Answer (score 1):

If your cpu has virtualization built into it, you can watch movies via Virtualbox running XP.

Comment: This not watching on Linux, this is watching on Windows on Linux.

Comment: @MiffTheFox and that is the defacto answer for most netflix / linux users

Answer (score 0):

You can't because Netflix uses DRM technologies to protect its content via Silverlight (available for Windows and OSX), more specifically [Microsoft Playready](http://www.microsoft.com/playready/default.mspx), and since Novell doesn't pay the license fee for the DRM controlls to be included in Moonlight, sadly you'll never be able to watch streaming movies on Linux unless Netflix decides to do something about it.

I think you should call them and express your concerns about Linux unavailability.