# Is there a way to get Netflix streaming movies to work on Fedora 13?

Tags: fedora-13, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Watch Netflix “Instant Watch” in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/21315/watch-netflix-instant-watch-in-linux)

Is there some way to watch Netflix streaming movies on my Fedora 13 machine?
Can I install the windows version of Chrome and run it with Wine or something?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/21315/watch-netflix-instant-watch-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Cypher!
[Watch Netflix "Instant Watch" in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/21315/watch-netflix-instant-watch-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome runs on Linux. It says so [right here](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux&hl=en&hl=en&platform=linux).

The other suggestion is to run XP in a virtual machine under Fedora, but that might not be optimal.

Comment: yes, but netflix does not.