# Netflix on Firefox Linux: "EME has been preffed off"

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora, netflix, drm

I'm trying to watch Netflix on Firefox 53.0 (Fedora 24).

When I try to watch any video, I get the following error message:

> CREATE: Request mediaKeySystem access rejected: EME has been preffed off

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Accoridng to the [Netflix support pages](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/32661) (and I tested and confirmed it on my computer), in order for Firefox to be able to play Netflix video, you need to:

- Enable playback of HTML5 DRM media in Firefox. To do that, type `about:preferences#content` on the addres bar, and check "Play DRM Content".
- Try to watch the DRM-protected Netflix video again.
- Wait for Firefox to automatically install the "***Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google, Inc***" plugin (Firefox will automatically install it when you first try to watch any Netflix video).
- A dialog similar to the one below is displayed, just click "yes":
  [image]
- you can check that it is installed by visiting `about:addons` and clicking "plugins", there will be an entry named "Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google, Inc"

Comment: This helped but changed the error message for me.  I was also getting "The video on this page can’t be played. Your system may not have the required video codecs for: video/mp4;codecs=avc1.640028, audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.5" after a quick Google I found out I needed to install libav-tools and restart Firefox.